# create a python object/instance of format with equal signs

Tags: python, object, types, instance

I want to create a struct of the following format in python, when printed. Basically a dictionary, but with a equal sign instead of colon. I cannot find what exact type it is, but it should be possible

print obj1

> obj1 = {a = {aa = 1, ab = 2}, b = {ba = 3, bb = 5}, c = [1 2 4]}

Comment: That sounds like you should just use a dict and write a custom formatting function if you want to print a nonstandard string representation of the dict.

Answer (score 0):

it is invalid syntax. In python, you can not create a `dict` with equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class like this, whose `__str__` method will format the output of a dictionary:

```py
class DictionaryFormatter():
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self.obj1 = dictionary

    def __str__(self):
        obj1_str = str(self.obj1)
        obj1_str = obj1_str.replace("'", "")
        obj1_str = obj1_str.replace(":", " =")
        return f"obj1 = {obj1_str}"

d = {
    "a": {"aa": 1, "ab": 2},
    "b": {"ba": 3, "bb": 5},
    "c": [1, 2, 4]
}

print(DictionaryFormatter(d))
print("obj1 = {a = {aa = 1, ab = 2}, b = {ba = 3, bb = 5}, c = [1 2 4]}")
```

Output:

```
obj1 = {a = {aa = 1, ab = 2}, b = {ba = 3, bb = 5}, c = [1, 2, 4]}
obj1 = {a = {aa = 1, ab = 2}, b = {ba = 3, bb = 5}, c = [1 2 4]}
```

As you see the output is not perfect, as `c` is using commas, but that should be easy to fix. I hope you get the idea, and this is what you were looking for.